# Java using streams on abstract datatypes?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I can't understand entirely how streams work in Java. Can you make an abstract datatype like an MyArrayList and use stream on it somehow?

Something like:

```
MyDataType<MyClass> myList = new MyDataType<>();
myList.stream()
      .filter...and.so.on
```

MyDataType implements java.util.List but only certain operations (add, remove, size, isEmpty, toString).

Is there any way or I have to convert from my datatype to some datatype implemented in java?

My current solution (which is actually very unhealthy): 
Implement in MyDataType the operation ToArray. And do the following:

```
MyDataType<MyClass> myList = new MyDataType<>();
... loads of computation...
MyClass[] someList = myList.ToArray();
java.util.ArrayList badList = new java.util.ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(someList));
badList.stream()
```

With this, I lose some operations and my way of implementing them but at least I can use the streams and filtering...

Comment: `Stream` is an interface. `Collection` is another interface.

Comment: And ArrayList is concrete, not abstract. Perhaps better for you to explain in greater detail just what is motivating this question. What are you trying to do overall (not how are you trying to do it)?

Comment: I meant making my own datatype called ArrayList. I only made it more confusing with that example. So can I use streams on my variable myList from the code piece?

Comment: Again why are you contemplating this? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I used my own datatype in a bigger project and now I want to take it one step further and try streams. The ultimate goal is to experiment with java8 and of course, knowledge and curiosity.

Comment: Please explain more about "try streams" -- for what purpose? If you don't have a purpose, then the question makes no sense. To ask directly: what do you want to do with the stream? Perhaps you really need to use ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream and want to Serialize your objects? But I can't tell yet.

Comment: I want to do a filtering over the objects from myList, if they correspond with the criteria, I will use .collect on them. I don't know what more to tell you. This is exactly the code in words.

Comment: So `MyDataType` is a subtype of `List`?

Comment: Nope. MyDataType implements MyInterface, also made by me.

Comment: Then where do you think the `stream` method would come from? If you don't define it (and eventually implement it), it doesn't exist. It's very unclear what you're asking or what you're confused about.

Comment: And if I implement MyDataType over the java.util.List interface? How should I call .stream() then?

Comment: There's already a `default` implementation of it. Assuming you've implemented all the other things required by `List` you'll be able to call it directly.

Comment: Ugh ok so basically, if I make my own datatype and implement just some of the operations that I need, streams won't work? (I only implemented like 6-7 operations that I needed)

Comment: Is `MyDataType` the "datatype" that you're referring to? Does it contain an ArrayList or some other Collection derived class? If so, simply use the Stream available from the contained Collection.

Comment: Please try to answer these queries so that we can understand what you're doing. If your datatype implements Collection, have it extend AbstractCollection or AbstractList, and you'll inherit their `stream()` implementation. But again, I have no idea if this will fit your problem without more information. It's like you're trying to hide information from us for unknown reason. Please reconsider and ask as detailed a question as possible. I'm trying to help, really I am.

Comment: We cannot help until you provide more details. Which List operations exactly did you implemented? How they are implemented? Please edit your question adding more details (possibly including relevant parts of the source code of your `MyDataType` class)

Comment: I added my current solution which is basically... transforming temporarily from MyDataType to java.util.ArrayList. I couldn't find any better solution for now. I added some more details related to the operations and this is the msot relevant source code. These are really all the details. I want to use streams on a datatype made me but as I understand, it's impossible cause it doesn't have the operations that work with streams implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a custom collection and want to be able to generate a stream from it then the simplest approach is to implement a [`Spliterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html). Once you have done that creating a stream is trivial.

For example, if you have a class `Dongle` and have implemented a `DongleGroup` collection, then you could implement methods:

```
private Spliterator<Dongle> spliterator() {
    ...
}

public Stream<Dongle> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

Implementing a spliterator is not hard and there are good tutorials on it available. You can also convert an `Iterable` into a `Spliterator` using the default `spliterator` method.

Now you can happily use the various stream capabilities with your classes:

```
myDongleGroup.stream().filter(Dongle::isRed)...
```

Comment: I guess this would be the only solution, though it sounds like so much work, I'm not going to use it. I'll wait till tomorrow and see any others come, if not, this is it.